# Warning: Undefined array key in PHP 8.0

Tags: php, arrays, key, undefined

My webhotel have uppgrade to PHP version 8.0 The code is working but it's showing warningmessage on the homepage now.

I'ts something with my array.

```
Warning: Undefined array key "JS" in /customers/c/c/4/plf1x2.dk/httpd.www/test/svspeuro.php on line 1465 
Warning: Undefined array key "Vinst" in /customers/c/c/4/plf1x2.dk/httpd.www/test/svspeuro.php on line 1465 
Warning: Undefined array key "PWB" in /customers/c/c/4/plf1x2.dk/httpd.www/test/svspeuro.php on line 1468 Warning: 
Undefined array key "Vinst" in /customers/c/c/4/plf1x2.dk/httpd.www/test/svspeuro.php on line 1468 Warning: 
Undefined array key "oavgjord" in /customers/c/c/4/plf1x2.dk/httpd.www/test/svspeuro.php on line 1471  here
```

I Have tried with

```
enterif (isset($matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['omgångar'])){
    $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['omgångar']+=1;
    } code here
```

but it doesnt work it's get a empty value.

Here is the code.
I hope someone can help me?

```
// Sorterar ut lagnamn och resultat
$file = file($filename);
$result = array_merge($file,$resultatarray)
$matchesLines = array();


foreach($result as $line) {

  if(preg_match('/^([a-öA-Ö]+\D)-([a-öA-Ö]+\D) (\d+)-(\d+)/',  $line,  $data)){
    $Hemma_Lag = $data[1];
    $Borta_Lag = $data[2];
    $Hemma_Resultat = $data[3];
    $Borta_Resultat=$data[4];

    $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['Vinst'] += 0;
    $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['Vinst'] += 0;
    $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['oavgjord'] += 0;
    $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['oavgjord'] += 0;
    $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['Förlust'] += 0;
    $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['Förlust'] += 0;

    if ($Hemma_Resultat == $Borta_Resultat){
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['lag'] = $Hemma_Lag;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['poang']+=1;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['mål'] += $Hemma_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['måli'] += $Borta_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['oavgjord'] += 1;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['lag'] = $Borta_Lag;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['poang'] +=1;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['mål'] += $Borta_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['måli'] += $Hemma_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['oavgjord'] += 1;
    }

    if ($Hemma_Resultat > $Borta_Resultat){
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['lag'] = $Hemma_Lag;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['poang']+=3;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['mål'] += $Hemma_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['måli'] += $Borta_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['Vinst'] += 1;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['lag'] = $Borta_Lag;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['poang'] +=0;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['mål'] += $Borta_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['måli'] += $Hemma_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['Förlust'] += 1;
    }

    if ($Hemma_Resultat < $Borta_Resultat) {
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['lag'] = $Hemma_Lag;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['poang']+=0;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['Förlust'] += 1;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['mål'] += $Hemma_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['måli'] += $Borta_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['lag'] = $Borta_Lag;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['poang'] +=3;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['Vinst'] += 1;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['mål'] += $Borta_Resultat;
      $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['måli'] += $Hemma_Resultat;
    }
    
    if (isset($matchesLines[$Borta_Lag])){
    $matchesLines[$Borta_Lag]['omgångar']+=1;
    $matchesLines[$Hemma_Lag]['omgångar']+=1;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a PHP 8 specific thing. I think this is probably just a difference in the `display_errors` setting in php.ini in your updated PHP version. I think you were already getting these warnings previously, due to uninitialized variables, but they just weren't being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I Think you are right.  But the problem is still There. How do I get rid of the massage? I can't  understand how to declare the variables.

Comment: @Don'tPanic no it's an elevation on the part of PHP 8.0

Comment: @Martin Oh yeah, you're right.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've just discovered it and it's causing me some sad times.... my error logs are no longer empty `:-(`

Comment: I turn it off.   // Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [PHP 8.0 has elevated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) this notice and a bunch of other *notices* to now be **warnings** :

> A number of notices have been converted into warnings:
>
> ```
> Attempting to read an undefined variable.
> Attempting to read an undefined property.
> Attempting to read an undefined array key.
> ...
> ```